# Publish file in a release TFS

Tags: tfs, publish, release

I'm trying to work with release in TFS, I add a task a "Copy Publish Artifact" to publish a file that will be generated in a release it gives me the error:

```
##[error]System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'StagingFolder' because it is null.
```

I test with the task "Windows machine file copy" it gives the error 53

```
Copy started for - '\\documents-oab.si.fr.intSraorange\alfresco\webdav\Sites\cc-dtp\documentLibrary\andbox_Auto /user:*****  *****'
2018-05-07T08:43:15.7623208Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Copying failed for resource : 
2018-05-07T08:43:15.7623208Z 
2018-05-07T08:43:15.7623208Z       Failed to connect to the path \\documents-oab.si.fr.intSraorange\alfresco\webdav\Sites\cc-dtp\documentLibrary\andbox_Auto /user:***** ***** with the user ***** for copying.
2018-05-07T08:43:15.7623208Z     System error 53 has occurred. 
2018-05-07T08:43:15.7623208Z The network path was not found.
```

My questions is: how can i publish file generated in a release is there any method ??

Comment: My questions is: how can i publish file generated in a release is there any method ??

Answer (score 0):

You can not publish an artifact in a release using staging folder, because it really does not exist. It is a build variable only.

When you used the "Windows machine file copy", is is showing you in the log that "The network path was not found.".

Or it really does not exist or the user running the task nas no permission to access it.

To copy a file to one location to another you could:

- Use a Windows Machine File Copy
- Use a File copy task
- Use a powershell command to copy files
- Use a command line to copy files